# Exim4 as smarthost with SSL?

Tags: ssl, smtp, exim

I want to use exim4 as a smarthost to send email using an smtp mail account over ssl. I've seen the hosts_require_tls option, but I need SSL and not TLS.  How should I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by “I need SSL and not TLS”? SSL and TLS are the same family of protocols, SSL is the name for the older versions and TLS is the name for the newer versions. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/SSL (which is also http://en.wikipedia.org/TLS).

Comment: I knew that TLS is the same family, I just didn't know that they are compatible / TLS also means SSL support. As TLS is newer I assumed it would only support TLS.

Comment: @Gilles, unfortauntely, many people mean STARTTLS when they use the word TLS (completely ignoring the word "START", which is the important part, of course). stefan.at.wpf, you need to find out whether your server supports SMTPS or SMTP+STARTTLS, or both (see [this on SF](http://serverfault.com/a/368574/47187)).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `protocol` option in your smtp transport to `smtps`. This will cause Exim to connect out on port 465, and initiate TLS as soon as it connects to the remote server.

See the documentation for `protocol` at http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_smtp_transport.html for more information.